# Handling nested classes

Tags: java

I am having difficulties to handle the following classes gracefully:

Suppose I have the following class A:

```
class A{

  B b1;

  class B{

    C c1;
    D d1;

    class C{
    .
    .
    .
    }

    class D{
    .
    .
    .
    }

  }
}
```

and I have also class AA:

```
class AA{

  B b1;

  class B{

    C c1;
    E e1;

    class C{
    .
    .
    .
    }

    class E{
    .
    .
    .
    }

  }
}
```

I need to create and initialize objects of A or AA depending on some flag state.
Notice that class B inside class A is nesting class D whereas class B inside class AA is nesting class E !

The automatic thought I had is to derive them from some base class and use a factory.
Then I would get an object which I can use, but then I would face the need to work with D or E objects.
But I don't know exactly how to implement this idea. Is it possible at all? Is there a better way of achieving it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd try to avoid multiple levels of inner classes, as it often creates awfully complicated code.

In your example, since `A` and `AA` have a field of type `B`, eliminating the need for an inner class is easy:

```
class Bar {
   Foo foo;

   static class Foo { // this is just a nested class now, it can easily be moved to top level
       private Bar parent;
   }

   void setFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
      foo.parent = this;
   }
}
```

*(The above is just a simplified example to show the mechanism, in real code you should make additional checks, i.e. `foo != null` and what should happen if `foo.parent` is already set to a non-null value)*

The situation is slightly different if both `A` and `B` are immutable, in that case instantiation of `B` has to be strictly controlled by `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to nest classes that way first revise your design. If you really want to stick with it you can just create a property object and let programmatically (a factory?) instantiate the right ones.

```
class B{

   C c1;
   // ...

   // possible a D & E parent class
   Object X;
}

class A
  B b1;
  // ...
}
```

depending on your needs you can combine generics and/or constructors in a way instatianting A can lead to conditional instantiation of (the correct B). In this scenario leting all this logic in a factory makes sense IMHO